# SAML - Manage User Details in IdP using SSOCircle

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml

I'm setting up Web SSO using the Spring Security SAML extension, and I'm using [SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/) as my IdP.  Following the Spring Security [quick start](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html), I was able to get up and running.  However, I want the IdP to also provide additional user details such as role / organization information.  How/Where does the IdP communicate additional user details?  Does anyone know if we can provide additional information with SSOCircle?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure SSOCircle IDP to send additional attributes along with the SAML assertion. For example: last name, first name and email address. For specific requirements you should contact SSOCircle directly for a custom setup.